# Как импортировать js файл в TypeScript проект?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Предположим, есть файл config.js, в котором описана функция-конструктор:

```
function ConfigService () {
this.greeting = function() {console.log('Hello World');}
}
```

Как должен выглядеть заголовочный файл, чтобы импортировать без ошибок?

Comment: Что такое заголовочный файл в терминах typescript?

Comment: Заголовочный или декларативный typescript файл - с расширением .d.ts, который, как я понимаю, как раз служит для того, чтобы подключить .js файлы.

Comment: Строго говоря `.js` файлы можно подключать и без `.d.ts`, только не будет никакой статической типизации. В вашем случае поскольку это функция-конструктор, можно описать класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Этот метод подходит для тех, кто использует nodeJS.
В .js файле необходимо указать

```
module.exports.ConfigService = ConfigService;
```

В файле .d.ts просто экспортировать функцию или класс, если в .js файле определена функция-конструктор:

```
expot class ConfigService {
  smt: {};
}
```

или

```
export function ConfigService(): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае поскольку это функция-конструктор, можно описать класс.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export class ConfigService {
    constructor();
    greeting(): void;
  }
}
```

Посмотреть, как и что создавать можно в [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html).